# Issue in Shared code not working in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

I want to integrate Shared code between React Native and React JS so I create one module which is uploaded on Gitlab and I gave path to my React JS project as below. First of all refer my project structure

[image]

In gitmodule it is like below image

[image]

In My App.js file i want to access service--> api.ts file so I gave path to my App.js file as below

```
import {getUserData} from '../src/rn_sharecodecommon/Service/api'
 const { isLoading, data, message, getUser } = getUserData()
  useEffect(()=>{
    getUser('users')
},[])
```

and My Service/api.ts file code as below

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export const getUserData = () => {
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const getUser = async (url) => {
    console.log("URL-->", url);
    let res;
    try {
        console.log("URL--> 1");
      setIsLoading(true);
      axios.get('https://api.github.com/'+url).then((response) => {
        res = response.data;
        setIsLoading(false);
        setData(response.data);
        console.log("API lOfi",response.data);
      });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("URL--> 2");
      setIsLoading(false);
      setMessage(error);
    }
};
return {
  isLoading,
  message,
  data,
  getUser,
  };
}
```

When i run above code in React JS it is showing me error like below

```
Can't resolve '../src/rn_sharecodecommon/Service/api' in '/Volumes/Data/WebProject/SSCode/sharecode/src'
```

[image]

Any Idea how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved by make small change in import as below

```
import { getUserData } from './rn_sharecodecommon/Service/api.ts'
```